# Non Kohen Blessing a Kohen

Tags: halacha, blessing, kohen-priest

Is it permissible for a non Kohen such as an Israelite or a Levi to give any type of blessing to a Kohen?

Comment: In Gemara berachot Hashem asked rabbi ishmael to bless him. So an israelite can bless a Cohen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? We all have the power to give brachot. No matter who gives to whom.